# Completeness relations in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How should I approch the following?

A group $G$, order $n$ , has $R^{(\mu)}$ as a irreducible matrix representation of dimension $l_{\mu}$.

We have the following ortogonality relation:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{g~\epsilon~G} R^{(\mu)}_{ij}(g)\bar{R}^{(\nu)}_{ml}(g) = \frac{n}{l_{\mu}} \delta_{\mu\nu}\delta_{im}\delta_{jl} ~.
\end{equation}

From that, how to verify the following completeness relation?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mu=1}^{N} \sum_{i,j=1}^{l_{\mu}} \frac{l_{\mu}}{n} R^{(\mu)}_{ij}(g)\bar{R}^{(\mu)}_{ij}(g') = \delta_{gg'} ~.
\end{equation}

And, also, how to verify the following completeness relation of the characters of this group?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mu=1}^{N} \sqrt{\frac{c_{k}}{n}}\chi^{(\mu)}(k) \sqrt{\frac{c_{k'}}{n}}\bar{\chi}^{(\mu)}(k') = \delta_{kk'} ~,
\end{equation}

$k$ represents a class and $c_{k}$ is the number of elements in each class.

Books and references would also be helpful.

Comment: I think this result is non-trivial and but I also find this very interesting.

Comment: All that is true if $G$ is more generally  a topological connected compact group and the statements are part of the well-known Peter-Weyl theorem. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem)

Comment: Off the top of my head, you should check a group theory book such as Brocker/Dieck, Tinkham, Hammermesh, 1st volume of Cornwell or perhaps Wu Ki Tung (I am not sure about the last, though).

Comment: Your second equation seems to have a typo: the $\nu$ should be a $\mu$. As written, it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: You didn’t explain what $N$ is.